# How to convert group by SQL query to Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Please guide me how to convert this query into an Entity Framework query?

```
select 
    sum(Amount), convert(varchar(10), CreatedOn, 120)
from 
    [TableName]
group by 
    convert(varchar(10), CreatedOn, 120)
order by 
    convert(varchar(10), CreatedOn, 120)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the type of your CreatedOn column is datetime, you can make a good use of DbFunctions.TruncateTime for this situation:

```
ICollection<GroupedRow> result = context.TableName.GroupBy(t => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.CreatedOn))
            .Select(g => new GroupedRow()
            {
                Sum = g.Sum(t => t.Amount),
                DateCreatedOn = g.Key
            }).OrderBy(c => c.DateCreatedOn).ToList();
```

where GroupedRow is:

```
class GroupedRow
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Although the linq to entities query looks clean, the generated sql for Sql Server 2014 will look like this:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[C3] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C3]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2], 
    1 AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[K1] AS [K1], 
        SUM([Extent1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            convert (datetime2, convert(varchar(255), [Extent1].[CreatedOn], 102) ,  102) AS [K1], 
            [Extent1].[Amount] AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Extent1]
        GROUP BY [K1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

The 102 style represents the format "yyyy.mm.dd" according to [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) documentation.

At least, then you can format your date as you want in your UI, because you end up with a DateTime object, but in your case maybe you'll want to use `Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using linq:

```
var results = TableName.GroupBy(x => x.CreatedOn).OrderBy(x=>x.CreatedOn).ToList();
```